# Why does linearization in Python give this bizarre result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

Consider this simplified situation:

```
class Decoder:
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__bytes__().decode('ascii')

class Comment(Decoder, bytes):
    def __bytes__(self):
        return b'#' + self
```

Usage:

```
Comment(b'foo')
```

Prints:

```
b'foo'
```

Instead of expected:

```
#foo
```

Regardless of the order in `Comment.mro()` (i.e. I can swap `Decoder` and `bytes` in the supeclass list), `Decoder.__str__()` is never called.

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Comment(b'foo')` calls `Comment.__new__`, which, not being defined, resolves to either `Decoder.__new__` or `bytes.__new__`, depending on the order in which you list them in the definition of `Comment`.

The MRO for `Comment` is `Comment`, `bytes`, `Decoder`, `object`. However, the functions actually being called are:

1. `Comment.__new__`, to create a new object. Since that function isn't defined, we next call `bytes.__new__`, which is defined. It effectively just calls `object.__new__(Comment, b'foo')`, giving you your final object.
2. To *display* the return value of `Comment`, the interpreter tries to call `Comment.__repr__`, not `Comment.__str__`. Again, the function isn't defined, so it falls back to `bytes.__repr__`, giving the observed result.

Comment: That is incorrect. Meaning, you didn't understand the question. When `Comment(b'foo')` is called, it is called interactively in the interactive shell, which, for the purpose of printing needs to come up with some string represenation of whatever was created. At that point, I expect some `__str__()` method to be called.

Comment: That expectation is false; `__str__` never gets called, because you haven't called `str` explicitly or used `print()`.

Comment: Linearization isn't the issue here; it's understanding which dunder methods are called and why.

Answer (score 0):

If you use print function you get expected result, but if you look at result from console you see the result of `__repr__` method. If you need it works in this way you can call `self.__str__()` from `__repr__`

```
>>msg = Comment(b'foo')
>>msg
b'foo'
>>print(msg)  # or str(msg)
'#foo'
```

There you can read how it works [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)